# I want to convert dynamic Json to the model in Dart. and show as listView expandable widget

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the response from server

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "Appliances": [
            {
                "HandBlenders": 5
            },
            {
                "AirConditioners": 6
            }
        ],
        "Health & Personal Care": [
            {
                "Trimmers": 3
            }
        ],
        "Electronics": [
            {
                "Smartphones": 4
            },
            {
                "Laptops": 7
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I want output like this

```
List<Categories> categories = [
  Categories(
    'Appliances',
    ['HandBlenders', 'AirConditioners'],
    [5, 6]
  ),
  Categories(
    'Health & Personal Care',
    ['Trimmers'],
    [3]
  ),
    Categories(
    'Electronics',
    ['Smartphones', 'Laptops'],
    [4, 7]
  ),
];
```

And want to show that in Expandable list view builder, Please Suggest, with tap on sub category I get Id of the product

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your `Category Model` Class

```
factory Categories.fromMap(Map item) {
    List<String> subCategoryList = [];
    List<int> unitsList = [];
    item.values.first.forEach((element) {
      print(element);
      subCategoryList.addAll((element as Map<String,int>).keys);
      unitsList.addAll(element.values);
    });
    return Categories(
        item.keys.first,
        subCategoryList,
        unitsList
    );
  }
```

and in your function where you get the response provided add the following lines of code after the response call

```
List<Categories> categories = [];
if(response["success"){
  var data = response["data"] as Map<String,Object>;
  data.forEach((key, value) {
    Categories category = Categories.fromMap({key:value});
    categories.add(category);
  });
}
```